# How to think about multiple independent events?

Tags: probability, self-study, independence

Suppose $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal F$ are independent events in a probability space, and also that $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal G$ are independent.  Is $\mathcal F \cap \mathcal G$ independent of $\mathcal E$?  If so, how can I demonstrate that?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I find it a bit disappointing that people just *did* the problem here.  Regardless of whether the "self-study" tag is there, we all know what it's like to me told an answer and what's it's like to be lead to one.  The latter is almost always more meaningful.

Comment: I upvoted you, now I am even wondering there are something missing for both my solution and jtobin's solution. Since both of us assume that A , B and C are mutually independent which might not be correct.

Comment: Hmmm.  That's a good point.  I'm gonna actually work this out myself.

Comment: In fact this is not true.  I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: What is especially disappointing is that this question has received _three_ incorrect answers, though two may yet be modified. Consider two independent tosses of a fair coin, and let $B= \{HT,HH\}$ and $C=\{HT,TT\}$ be the events that the first and second tosses resulted in Heads and Tails respectively, and $A=\{HT,TH\}$ the event that exactly one toss resulted in Heads. Thus, $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac 12$, $P(A\cap B)=P(A\cap C)=\frac 14$, so that $A,B$ are independent as are $A,C$. But $P(B\cup C)=\frac 34,P(A\cap(B\cup C)=\frac 14 \neq P(A)P(B\cup C)$, that is, $A$ and $B\cup C$ are dependent.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Nice counter example. Perhaps consider expanding it as an answer? I guess the OP would be (or at least I certainly am) interested whether there is some "general logic" or idea how to arrive to such conclusion. I mean, I don't see what was your idea to write such counter example.

Answer (score 12):

> Let $A$ and $B$ be independent events, and let $A$ and $C$ be independent events. How do I show that $A$ and $B\cup C$ are independent events as well?

You cannot show this result because it does not hold for all $A, B, C$
enjoying these properties. Consider the following counter-example.

Consider two independent tosses of a fair coin. Let $B=\{HT,HH\}$ and $C=\{HT,TT\}$ be the events that the first and second tosses resulted in Heads and Tails respectively. Let $A=\{HT,TH\}$ be the event that exactly one toss resulted in Heads.

Then, $P(A)=P(B)=P(C) = \frac 12$ while $P(A\cap B) = P(A\cap C) =
\frac 14$ and so $A$ and $B$ are independent events as are $A$ and
$C$ independent events. Indeed, $B$ and $C$ are also independent
events (that is, $A$, $B$, and $C$ are *pairwise* independent events).
However, 
$$P(A) = \frac 12 ~ \text{and}~ P(B\cup C)=\frac 34 ~ \text{while}~ P(A\cap(B\cup C)) =\frac 14 \neq P(A)P(B\cup C)$$
and so $A$ and $B\cup C$ are *dependent* events.

---

Putting away our counter-example, let us consider what conditions
are needed to make $A$ and $B\cup C$ independent events. The other
answers have already done the work for us. We have that
\begin{align}
P(A\cap (B\cup C)) &= P((A\cap B) \cup (A\cap C))\\
&= P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap C) - P(((A\cap B) \cap (A\cap C))\\
&= P(A)P(B) + P(A)P(C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)\\
&= P(A)\left(P(B) + P(C) - P(B\cap C)\right) 
+ \left(P(A)P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)\right)\\
&= P(A)P(B\cup C) + \left[P(A)P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)\right]
\end{align}
and so $P(A\cap (B\cup C))$ equals $P(A)P(B \cup C)$ (as is needed
to prove that $A$ and $B\cup C$ are independent events) exactly
when $P(A)P(B\cap C)$ equals $P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(A\cap (B\cap C))$,
that is when $A$ and $B\cap C$ are independent events.

> $A$ and $B\cup C$ are independent events whenever $A$ and $B\cap C$ are independent events.

Notice that whether $B$ and $C$ are independent 
or not is not relevant to the
issue at hand: in the counter-example above, $B$ and $C$ *were*
independent events and yet $A = \{HT, TH\}$ and $B\cap C = \{HT\}$ were
not independent events.  Of course, as noted by Deep North,
if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are *mutually* independent events (which
requires not just independence of $B$ and $C$ but also for
$P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$ to hold), then $A$ and $B\cap C$
are indeed independent events. Mutual independence 
of $A$, $B$ and $C$ is a *sufficient* condition.

Indeed, if $A$ and $B\cap C$ are independent events, then, together
with the hypothesis that $A$ and $B$ are independent, as are $A$ and
$C$ independent events, we can show that $A$ is independent of 
*all $4$* of the events $B\cap C, B\cap C^c, B^c\cap C, B^c\cap C^c$,
that is, of all $16$ events in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by
$B$ and $C$; one of these events is $B\cup C$.

Comment: I would add that a trivial way to make the framed condition hold is $B$ and $C$ disjoint, since then $P(B\cap C)=0$.

Comment: @Miguel Yes, that is another _sufficient_ condition for $A$ and $B\cup C$ to be independent events, just like mutual independence of $A,B,C$ is a _sufficient_ condition as my answer says. My answer is about what is the _necessary_ condition for $A$ and $B\cup C$ to be independent events.

Answer (score 6):

Two things.

1)  Is there some way you know to rewrite the event $A \cap (B\cup C)$.  Intuitively, we know how A,B and A,C interact, but we don't know how B,C interact.  So $(B\cup C)$ is getting in our way.

2) Is there some way you know of rewriting $P(X\cup Y)$?

Even if you don't immediately get the answer, please edit your answer with the answers to these questions and we'll go from there.

**edit**

Please check me on this.  I believe I have a counterexample.

Rolling a die to get X.

A: X < 4

B: X in {1, 4}

C: X in {1, 5}

Comment: I would go by this answer! Try to work it out yourself! you do not gain too much by just seeing the answer!

Answer (score 2):

As per Dilip Sarwate's comment, these events are demonstrably not independent.

The typical way I would try to prove independence proceeds like this:

\begin{align*}
P(A, B \cup C)
  & = P(\{A, B\} \cup \{A, C\}) & \text{distributive property} \\
  & = P(A, B) + P(A, C) - P(A,B,C) & \text{sum rule}
\end{align*}

and here you'd like to factor $P(A)$ out of the expression in order to establish the property $P(A, B \cup C) = P(A)P(B \cup C)$, which would be sufficient to prove independence.  However if you try to do that here, you get stuck:

$$
P(A, B) + P(A, C) - P(A,B,C) = P(A) \{ P(B) + P(C) - P(B,C \, | \, A) \}
$$

Note that the braced expression is *almost* $P(B) + P(C) - P(B,C)$, which would get you to your goal.  But you have no information that allows you to reduce $P(B,C \, | \, A)$ any further.

Note that in my original answer I had sloppily asserted that $P(B, C \, | \, A) = P(A)P(B, C)$ and thus erroneously claimed that the result asked to be proved was true; it's easy to mess up!

But given that it proves to be difficult to demonstrate independence in this way, a good next step is to look for a counterexample, i.e. something that falsifies the claim of independence.  Dilip Sarwate's comment on the OP includes exactly such an example.

Comment: Why is $P(A,B,C)$ on the second line equal to $P(A)P(B,C)$ on the third line? It is not given that $A$ is independent of $B\cap C$, just of $B$, and of $C$ _separately.

Comment: So, after your edit, is it just the _derivation_ that is sloppy but the result claimed is itself correct, that is, $A$ is indeed independent of $B\cup C$ as the OP is tasked with proving? Or is it that the derivation does not prove the claim that $A$ is independent of $B\cup C$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate My derivation does not prove the claim; my edit also changed the erroneous $=$ assertion to $\neq$ in an attempt to make this clear.   I'll edit the answer again to be more explicit.

Comment: OK, +1 for fixing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$P[A \cap(B \cup C)]=P[(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)]=P(A \cap B)+P(A \cap C)-P[( A \cap B)\cap (A \cap C)]=P(A)*P(B)+P(A)*P(C)-P(A \cap B \cap C)$

$P(A)*P(B \cup C)=P(A)[P(B)+P(C)-P(B \cap C)]=P(A)*P(B)+P(A)*P(C)-P(A)*P( B \cap C)$

Now, we need to show $P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A)*P( B \cap C)$

If $A, B,C$ are mutually independent,the results are obvious.

While the condition is $A$ and $B$ are independent and $A$ and $C$ are independent do not guarantee independent of $B$ and $C$

Therefore, the OP may need to reexamine the condition of the question.

Comment: In your _second_ long equation, you got a $-P(A)P(B\cap C)$ term when you multiplied out that middle expression. But you wrote $-P(A\cap B \cap C)$ instead, that is, you equated $P(A)P(B\cap C)$ and $P(A\cap B \cap C)$, in effect assuming that $A$ and $B\cap C$ are independent. Why is that?

Comment: Thanks, it is an assumed independent which may not be correct.