# $X_i, X_j$ independent when $i≠j$, but $X_1, X_2, X_3$ dependent?

Tags: probability, distributions, independence

I've seen the statement:

> It's possible that random variables $X_i, X_j$ are independent for $i≠j$, but $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are dependent.

I haven't been able to find examples of this though.

Any examples?

Comment: This question has been answered many times on stats.se. Search for "pair wise independent" random variables.

Comment: Actually, I must withdraw my comment above. This question has not been explicitly asked previously, but some answers to other, related, questions (e.g. [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21429/6633) and [this other one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/173192/6633)) do discuss this issue.

Comment: I gave an example which is essentially the same one as in the answer by JohnK. I have edited the answer to include another example; _standard normal random variables_ that are _pairwise_ independent but _not_ mutually independent: their joint density is _not_ the product of the univariate marginal densities.

Comment: $X_1,X_2\sim\text{i.i.d.}$ and each equal to $0$ or $1$ with equal probabilties, and $X_3$ is the mod-$2$ sum of $X_1$ and $X_2.$ Then $X_1, X_3 \sim \text{i.i.d.}$ and $X_2,X_3\sim\text{i.i.d.}$ but obviously $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are not independent.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example of this, attributed to S. Benstein.

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ have the joint pmf

$$p\left(x_1, x_2, x_3 \right) =\begin{cases} \frac{1}{4} & \left(x_1, x_2, x_3 \right) \in \left\{ (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (1,1,1) \right\} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}$$

Then by summing out the third variable it is easy to see that the joint pmf of $X_i$ and $X_j$, $i\neq j$ is

$$p_{ij} (x_i, x_j)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{4} & (x_i, x_j) \in \left\{ (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1) \right\} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases} $$

Finally, the marginal pmf of $X_i$ is

$$p_i(x_i) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} & x_i= 0, 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Now, note that for $i\neq j$

$$p_{ij} (x_i, x_j) =p_i (x_i) p_j (x_j)$$

and thus $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent. **However**

$$p(x_1, x_2, x_3) \neq  p_1 (x_1) p_2 (x_2) p_3 (x_3)$$

and so $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are *not* independent. Thus pairwise independence does not imply mutual independence. The latter is a stronger condition and it's usually the one we use with random samples.

Comment: Why is the joint p.m.f of $p(x1,x2,x3)$ not $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}$? If one'd try to "induce" it from the single variable p.m.f? Also what does "summing out" mean?

Comment: @mavavilj It's not $1/8$ because there are only 4 equilikely tuples. It would have been $1/8$ if we would allow all possible configurations, in which case there would be $2^3$ outcomes.

Comment: But they aren't coherent then? I mean, if the image of $p_i(x_i)$ is $\{0,1\}$ and the image of $p_{ij}(x_i,x_j)$ is $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$, then why is the image of $p_{ijk}(x_i,x_j, x_k)$ not $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}\times \{0,1\}$? I'm thinking in the "inductive" way here.

Comment: @mavavilj It doesn't have to be like that. You are not taking the dependence into account.

Comment: If one starts from $p_i(x_i)$ and induces, then is there a dependence?

Comment: @mavavilj It seems to me that you are confused with the concept of "marginal" distribution. I would urge you to study a little more the relation between joint and marginal distributions.

Answer (score 10):

$X$, $Y$ independent Bernoulli$(\frac 12)$ and $Z= X+Y-2XY$ is an example of three random variables that are pairwise independent but not
mutually independent.

It is easy to show that $Z$ is also Bernoulli$(\frac 12)$ and that $(X,Z)$ 
and $(Y,Z)$ are *pairs* of independent random variables, and of
course, $(X,Y)$ is a *pair* of independent random variables by
assumption. (If you feel too lazy to carry this out for yourself,
note that the answer by @JohnK essentially uses $X_1=X, X_2=Y,
X_3 = 1-Z$).  Thus, $X,Y,Z$ are
said to be *pairwise independent* random variables. However, for
$X,Y,Z$ to be called *mutually independent* random variables, their
*joint* probability mass function must factor into the product
of the individual (marginal) probability mass functions, that is,
if $X, Y, Z$ take on values in the sets $\{x_i\}, \{y_j\}, \{z_k\}$
respectively, then

> $X,Y,Z$ are said to be *mutually independent* random variables if
>   for **all** choices of $x_i, y_j, z_k$,
>   $$P\{X=x_i, Y=y_j, Z = z_k\} = P\{X=x_i\}P\{Y = y_j\}P\{Z = z_k\}.$$

In the example above, it is easy to verify that 
$$P\{X=1,Y=1,Z=1\} = 0 \neq \frac 18 = P\{X=1\}P\{Y=1\}P\{Z=1\}$$
and so $X,Y,Z$ **cannot** be called
mutually independent random variables.

---

Lest you think that it is necessary to use discrete random variables
to have examples such as the one above, consider three *standard
normal random variables* $X,Y,Z$ whose joint probability
density function
$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)$ is **not** $\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(z)$ where
$\phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal density, but rather

$$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} 2\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(z)
& ~~~~\text{if}~ x \geq 0, y\geq 0, z \geq 0,\\
& \text{or if}~ x < 0, y < 0, z \geq 0,\\
& \text{or if}~ x < 0, y\geq 0, z < 0,\\
& \text{or if}~ x \geq 0, y< 0, z < 0,\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
Note that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are *not* a set of *three* jointly normal random variables but as will be described below, any two of these *is* indeed a pair of *independent* normal random variables.

We can calculate the joint density of any *pair* of the random variables,
(say $X$ and $Z$) by integrating out the joint density with respect to
the unwanted variable, that is,
$$f_{X,Z}(x,z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\,\mathrm dy.
\tag{2}$$

- If $x \geq 0, z \geq 0$ or if $x < 0, z < 0$, then
  $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} 2\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(z), & y \geq 0,\\
  0, & y < 0,\end{cases}$ 
  and so $(2)$ reduces to
  $$f_{X,Z}(x,z) = \phi(x)\phi(z)\int_{0}^\infty 2\phi(y)\,\mathrm dy = 
  \phi(x)\phi(z).
  \tag{3}$$
- If $x \geq 0, z < 0$ or if $x < 0, z \geq 0$, then
  $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} 2\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(z), & y < 0,\\
  0, & y \geq 0,\end{cases}$ and so $(2)$ reduces to
  $$f_{X,Z}(x,z) = \phi(x)\phi(z)\int_{-\infty}^0 2\phi(y)\,\mathrm dy = 
  \phi(x)\phi(z).
  \tag{4}$$

In short, $(3)$ and $(4)$ show that $f_{X,Z}(x,z) = \phi(x)\phi(z)$ for *all* 
$x, z \in (-\infty,\infty)$ and so $X$ and $Z$ are
(*pairwise*) independent standard normal random variables. Similar
calculations (left as an exercise for the bemused
reader) show that $X$ and $Y$ are
(*pairwise*) independent standard normal random variables, and
$Y$ and $Z$ also are
(*pairwise*) independent standard normal random variables.  **But**
$X,Y,Z$ are **not** mutually independent normal random variables. Nor are the three of them together a set of jointly normal random variables.
Indeed, their *joint* density $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)$
does not equal the product $\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(z)$ of
their marginal densities for *any* choice of 
$x, y, z \in (-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: Incredible and clear example with the normal distributions, thanks for sharing! It has a very intuitive geometric picture as well - for me it was easy to imagine why this example worked by observing how lines parallel to the coordinate axis hit the support of the mass function. I think it also suggests how to construct similar examples for n normal random variables, with (n-1)-wise independence, but not full independence ... though its not clear to me what Boolean logical formula to use to pick the support. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One that's perhaps easier to think about comes from a chessboard.  Pick a point uniformly on the chessboard and consider

$X_1$: row number (1-8) modulo 2
$X_2$: column number (1-8) modulo 2
$X_3$: color, 0 for white,1 for black.

It's easy to see than any pair of these is independent: rows are independent of columns; row is independent of colour.  But if you know $X_1$ and $X_2$, you know $X_3$ exactly.