# Joint Distribution Independencies

Tags: independence, joint-distribution

I'm struggling to find the example asked above.

- Provide an example of a distribution P(X1,X2,X3) where for each i ≠ j, we have that (Xi ⊥ Xj) ∈ I(P), but we also have that (X1,X2 ⊥ X3) ∉ I(P). Where I(P) is a set of independencies that hold in P.

What actually does the state (X1,X2 ⊥ X3) mean? I guess it is something like "The joint distribution of X1 and X2 is independent of X3" is that correct? Can you guys give me an example of a joint P(X1,X2,X3) that satisfies those statements above? (Note that (X1,X2 ⊥ X3) DOESN'T belong to I(P))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming that "(X1,X2 ⊥ X3)" (which makes no sense to me)
is a typo for (X1,X2 | X3),** and translating the rest of
your jargon from an unspecified source as asking

*"Find an example of three random variables $X,Y,Z$ that are pairwise independent but for which $X$ and $Y$ are NOT conditionally independent given $Z$",*

see [this answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/180727/6633)
for an example of three Bernoulli random variables that have this property as well as an example of three normal random variables that
that have this property.

A different example can be found in [this answer on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2029303/15941) where $(X,Y,Z)$ is
uniformly distributed on four of the eight identical subcubes into which we can partition the cube $[0,1]^3$.  The subcubes are

- $[0,\frac 12]^3$ and $[\frac 12,1]^2\times[0,\frac 12]$ which sit on the $z=0$ plane.
- $[0,\frac 12]\times [\frac 12,1]^2$ and 
  $[\frac 12,1]\times[0,\frac 12]\times[\frac 12,1]$ which sit on the $z=\frac 12$ plane.

In the answer on math.SE, it is shown that $X, Y, Z$ are *pairwise*
independent $\mathcal U([0,1]$ random variables, that is, 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases}1
& 0 \leq x, y \leq 1,\\0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ and similarly for the other two pairs. In particular, note that the pairwise
independence of $X$ and $Z$ means that $f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z) = f_X(x)$ and similarly, we have that $f_{Y\mid Z}(y\mid z) = f_Y(y)$.
But, given that $Z = z \in [0,\frac 12]$, $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the set 
$$\left(\left[0,\frac 12\right]\times\left[0,\frac 12\right]\right)
\bigcup\left(\left[\frac 12,1\right]\times\left[\frac 12,1\right]\right).$$
That is, 
$$f_{X,Y\mid Z}(x,y\mid z) 
= \begin{cases}2,& 0 \leq x,y \leq \frac 12,\\
2,& \frac 12 \leq x,y \leq 1,\\
0, &\text{otherwise},\end{cases}
\quad \neq f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)f_{Y\mid Z}(y\mid z)$$

showing that $X$ and $Y$ are NOT conditionally independent for
any given value of $Z$ in $[0,\frac 12)$, and a similar calculation
holds when the value of $Z$ is in $(\frac 12, 1]$.

Comment: Your explanation seems Ok, but I'm a bit confused with your translation, I'm not sure if the statement "give Z", translates well. Correct me if I'm wrong but for us to have a Conditional Independence we should have the " | " character in the statement isn't that right?

Comment: I have put in the statements you want.