# pairwise-independent but not collectivley independent

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, independence, gaussian-process

Can we define a three dimensional multivariate Gaussian that is pairwise-independent but not collectively independent?

Answer (score 5):

Read literally, the answer to the OP's question

> Can we define a three dimensional multivariate Gaussian that is pairwise-independent but not collectively independent?

is **No**. If $X, Y, Z$ enjoy a three-dimensional *multivariate Gaussian* (a.k.a. multivariate normal or MVN) distribution, then it is *not* possible for $X, Y, Z$ to be *pairwise* independent random variables but *not* mutually independent random variables. As pointed out by whuber, if $X, Y, Z$ are pairwise independent, then
$$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=\operatorname{cov}(X,Z)=\operatorname{cov}(Y,Z)=0$$ so that the *covariance matrix* is a diagonal matrix (and so is its inverse a diagonal matrix). Consequently, the three-dimensional multivariate Gaussian density of $X, Y, Z$
factors into the product of the three marginal densities, which is the condition for mutual independence of $X, Y, Z$.

A slightly different question is whether it is possible for $X, Y, Z$  *individually* to be Gaussian random variables, for them to be *pairwise* independent, that is, for the *pairs* $(X,Y), (X,Z), (Y,Z)$ of random variables to be pairwise independent *Gaussian* random variables (and thus for each pair to have a *bivariate* Gaussian distribution), but for $X, Y, Z$ to *not* be independent Gaussian random variables or to enjoy a *trivariate* Gaussian distribution.  The answer to this question is **Yes** and an example of three such standard Gaussian (or standard normal) random variables is given in [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/180727/6633) to an earlier question on a similar topic.

Comment: +1 It might help to make your initial reasoning a little plainer: to wit, pairwise independence implies *each* covariance is zero; and when *all* covariances are zero, the marginals are independent.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the suggestion, which I have incorporated into my answer.