# Example of when A is independent of B and A is independent of C, but A is not independent of B∪C?

Tags: probability, independence

Just as the title asks, I can't seem to wrap my head around a situation in which that is true. Of course I know that since **A and B** and **A and C** are independent, that **P(A∩B)=P(A)P(B)** and **P(A∩C)=P(A)P(C)**. So what would be an example in which **P(A∩(B∪C))** is **not equal** to **P(A)P(B∪C)**?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/180729/919.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say we have two fair coins, and the following events:

$A$: First coin is heads, $B$: second coin is heads and $C:$ only one of the coins is heads.

These event definitions satisfy the first two conditions. However,

$$P(A\cap (B\cup C))=1/2$$

while $P(A)P(B\cup C)=1/2 \times 3/4=3/8$.